# Comparing a sequence of elements and replacing on match via XSLT/Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to do an intersect of sorts between two child elements in the same XML document.

```
<links>
 <old>
   <xref linkend="zzzzz">/chapter/subchapter[1]/section[2]/@id</xref>
   <xref linkend="aaaaa">/chapter/section[1]/@id</xref>
 </old>
 <new>
   <xref linkend="xxxxx">/chapter/subchapter[1]/section[2]/@id</xref>
   <xref linkend="sssss">/chapter/@id</xref>
 </new>
</links>
```

Whenever there is a match between the string path in new/xref and old/xref, I want to join the two elements and create an output like this:

```
<matches>
  <match old-linkend='zzzzz' new-linkend='xxxxx'>/chapter/subchapter[1]/section[2]/@id</match>
</matches>
```

This is my first attempt at comparing sequences so I'm a little lost. I am using XSLT 2.0 with Saxon.

Comment: you can do a select match on old/xref, then use a xsl:if with something like /new/xref[position()]. You may have to go to the parent, depending on how you do your match ie ../new/xref[position()].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the context of one particular `old/xref` you can check for a matching new one with

```
<xsl:variable name="matching" select="../../new/xref[. = current()]"/>
```

In the square brackets, `.` is the `new/xref` you're testing and `current()` is the `old/xref` you started from.  Checking whether this sequence is empty tells you whether or not there was a match.

```
<xsl:if test="$matching">
  <match old-linkend="{@linkend}" new-linkend="{$matching/@linkend}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </match>
</xsl:if>
```

If more than one `new/xref` matches this `old/xref` then the `new-linkend` attribute value template is subject to the [rules for constructing simple content](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-simple-content), which will concatenate the `linkend` values from *all* the matching `new/xref` elements together, separated by spaces.

Comment: What if there are multiple matches ?I was kinda expecting a template match of some kind.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck as this is XSLT 2.0 you'll get all the matching `linkend` values space separated.  If it were XSLT 1.0 then you'd just get one of them (the first in document order).